# WPF Popup user control on mouse over parent using style only

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to use the style on a popup to trigger it opening when it's parent is moused over. Also I would like a delay to be included as a given control may be surrounded by other controls which include their own popup windows.

I am also trying to have my application follow a MVVM format.

Popup Code:

```
        <Popup Style="{StaticResource PopUpStyle}">
        <Border Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}"
                Background="White"
                Margin="4">
            <HeaderedContentControl x:Name="hcc_Fields"
                                    Style="{StaticResource HCCStyleLP}"
                                    Header="{Binding Path=DisplayName}">
                <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource ContentControlStyle}"
                                Content="{Binding Path=Controls}" 
                                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource AreaTemplate}" 
                                />
            </HeaderedContentControl>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
```

As you can see, I am attempting to bind the content of the popup in the content control.

The popup itself shows fine, however it only occurs once. (Please note, this is my first time using triggers)

Style Code:

```
    <Style x:Key="PopUpStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" Value="Fade" />
    <Setter Property="Placement" Value="MousePoint" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalOffset" Value="-3" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalOffset" Value="-3" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
            <!--<Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True" />-->
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True" KeyTime="0:0:1" />
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                            <!--<DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="False" KeyTime="0:0:1" />-->
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <!--<Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True" />-->
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="False" KeyTime="0:0:1" />
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>                
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If I remove the storyboarding:

```
<Style x:Key="PopUpStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" Value="Fade" />
    <Setter Property="Placement" Value="MousePoint" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalOffset" Value="-3" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalOffset" Value="-3" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True" />
        </Trigger>
</Style>
```

The popup does not get stuck, and the child control can be used; However this does not include a delay which may enable you to get your mouse to the control you intended to interact with. Removing the storyboard on the trigger (but not the bound DataTrigger) seems to have a similar effect.

I have been attempting to find an answer for the past couple of days, however most implementations use code behind, or named references which goes against the grain of my application.

Any assistance is appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: Mvvm doesnt prevent you from using code-behind for **view**-logic, such as triggering a mouse effect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, that still goes against the grain of my program, currently there are no code-behind views. Ideally this style would be in line with that and could be used any where in my code without the requirement of going into the code-behind each control. Obviously if I cannot find a solution then that is the road I will need to go down.